# How to derive the below expression for resisting length of a hill road?

Tags: civil-engineering

[image]

The image above shows the longitudinal profile of a hill road. In order to fix the alignment of the hill road the concept of resisting length is used. How to obtain the expression as shown above for the resisting length for the hill road?

Comment: The text on your image is unreadible.

Comment: just zoom in a bit wud be quite legible tht way.

Comment: ROFL errr no hence the comment.

Comment: Where is $h_2$ in the image? You can find a definition in 3rd paragraf under "Resisting Length:" [here](https://www.engineeringenotes.com/highway-construction/hill-roads-alignment-geometric-design-and-maintenance-of-hill-roads/48805).

Comment: h2 is total ineffective rise and fall along the route. The link that you shared doesn't give the derivation and further had already checked it out .